# Implementing two UITableViews with the same custom cell for reuse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have currently have two `UITableView`s populated with contacts for the app. I have one for simply viewing them and editing/deleting and one for searching/picking contacts from a list. However, I'm getting a returned nil value when trying to use the same custom class cell for both `UITableView`s.

These are my two `cellForRowAtIndexPath` functions.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell") as! ContactCell
    let item = contacts[indexPath.row]
    cell.meetupLabel?.text = item.fullName
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell") as! ContactCell
    let item = contacts[indexPath.row]
    cell.label?.text = item.fullName
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you set different identifiers(SecondCell/FirstCell) for your cells in IB? I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table did not have a cell named `FirstCell` or `SecondCell`, the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:)` method will return nil, and you will need to construct the cell yourself.

```
// no don't do this.
let cell: ContactCell
if let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstCell") as? ContactCell {
    cell = c
} else {
    cell = ContactCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "FirstCell")
}
```

You should use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`, which was introduced in iOS 6, if you would like UIKit to construct the cell for you:

```
// swift 3
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstCell", 
                for: indexPath) as! ContactCell

// swift 2
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell",
                forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactCell
...
```

---

Also, check if you have given the correct reuse-identifiers to the cells correctly in the interface builder.

[image]

Comment: I suspect the last part of your answer is the key: You have to assign the reuse identifiers to the cells when you set up your table view in IB or it doesn't work.

Comment: Fantastic, it works. It always seems to the little things. Thanks!

Comment: @ggworean this shouldn't happen if you register the classes for the UITableView. Check the `registerNib` or `registerClass` methods

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are `getting nil`, my quick guess is that you haven't registered the cell at some point, runs earlier than this cell event. Look at [this thread on how to register cell](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uitableviewcell-reuse).

Comment: Since I'm doing the reuse identifier's through IB I don't need to register the class. It will actually cause conflicts.